# How do I add data from a user in firebase rather than replace what is already there?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The app presents users with a random quote. I want users to be able to save the quotes and see which ones they saved. I can get a single quote to save, however, anytime the save button is clicked again, it overrides the previously saved quote with the new one. I've tried to find the answer elsewhere, but I cannot seem to get it to work. Below is my current code. I've also tried replacing setValue with updateChildValues, but I get the error Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '[AnyHashable : Any]'.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

class QuotesViewController: UIViewController {

var ref: DatabaseReference?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = Database.database().reference()
    
}

@IBAction func backToMain(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "mainHome")
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        present(vc, animated: true)
}
@IBOutlet weak var quotesLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    ref!.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("Quotes").child("quote").setValue(quotesLabel.text!)
    
}

@IBOutlet weak var nextButtonOutlet: UIButton!
@IBAction func nextQuoteButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    let  quotesData = QuotesData()
    let randomQuote = quotesData.randomQuote()
    quotesLabel.text = randomQuote
      
}  
}
```

I've also tried:

ref!.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("Quotes").child("quote").updateChildValues(quotesLabel.text!)

Comment: What is the guy you refer to as 'firebase'?  Firestore?  Firebase Realtime Database?  Firebase Cloud Messaging?  Firebase Storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is expected, you basically are referencing the very same node `child("quote")` and trying to change its value. But if you want to have multiple quotes, what you need to do is to create multiple nodes under the parent `child("Quotes")` with different names.

One trivial way of doing so, you might append a different number to each new quote node, for example when you want to add a new quote, define the following path:

`child("Quotes").child("quote1").setValue("...")`

Path for another quote:

`child("Quotes").child("quote2").setValue("...")`
And so on.

Alternatively, you can use Firebase Database reference method `childByAutoId()` to generate unique names. You will use that method after defining the parent node:

`ref!.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("Quotes").childByAutoId().setValue(quotesLabel.text!)`

---

Note:

Try to avoid force unwrapping as much as you can because that makes your app more prone to crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add one more field inside your firebase database that must be a unique one

For first time adding data into firebase you can write something like this

```
 let key = ref.child("Quotes").childByAutoId().key
    let dict = ["quote": quotesLabel.text!,
                "quoteId" : key ?? ""
    ] as [String: Any]
```

And whenever you are saving the same quote then you can update the value inside the particular quoteID like this

```
     func updateDatainFirebase(quoteId:String,quote:String){
        let dict = ["quote": quotesLabel.text!,
                    "quoteId" : quoteId ?? ""
        ] as [String: Any]
        self.ref.child(quoteId).updateChildValues(dict)
        
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the autoId and it works perfectly! Very exciting to see this thing coming to life!

Comment: That's Great, You can accept and upvote the answer if you get the solution